# Pegar valor do radio button e verificar o que está selecionado

Tags: php

Tenho um form com um radio button com Pessoa física e pessoa jurídica.
Quero que se for selecionado o button pessoa física mude o atributo label do html para CPF caso contrário CNPJ, e aplique as mascaras de acordo com a seleção.

Não encontrei algo especifico sobre.
Estou tentando fazer com PHP.

É possível fazer isso com PHP ou só com JS?

Comment: Só com javascript

Answer (score 1):

Alterações no `DOM` em tempo real, somente podem ser feitas através do `javascript`, segue um exemplo do seu caso.

```js
let tipoPessoa = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="tipoPessoa"]');

let cpf = document.querySelector('#cpf');
let cnpj = document.querySelector('#cnpj');

tipoPessoa.forEach(function(value){

value.onclick = function(event){

  cnpj.style.display = 'none';
  cpf.style.display = 'none';
  
  document.querySelector('#'+event.target.value+'').style.display = 'block';
  
}

})
```

```css
#cpf {display: none;}
#cnpj {display: none;}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="tipoPessoa" value="cpf">Pessoa Física<br>
<input type="radio" name="tipoPessoa" value="cnpj">Pessoa Jurídica<br>

<input type="text" id="cpf" placeholder="Digite seu CPF"><br>
<input type="text" id="cnpj" placeholder="Digite seu CNPJ">
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloca o código para que possamos nos basear no que você deseja. E quanto a pergunta o melhor é fazer com javascript. como o exemplo abaixo.

```js
var radio = document.getElementsByName("check");

function funcao(){
  for(var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){

    if (radio[i].checked && radio[i].value == "Pessoa Física") {
      document.getElementById("labelCPF").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("cpf").style.display = "block"
      
      document.getElementById("labelCNPJ").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cnpj").style.display = "none"

    } else if (radio[i].checked && radio[i].value == "Pessoa Jurídica") {
      document.getElementById("labelCNPJ").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("cnpj").style.display = "block"

      document.getElementById("labelCPF").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cpf").style.display = "none"

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Tipo pessoa</h3>
<div id="tipoPessoa" onchange="funcao()">
<label>Pessoa Física</label>
<input type="radio" name="check" value = "Pessoa Física">
<label>Pessoa Jurídica</label>
<input type="radio" name="check" value = "Pessoa Jurídica"> 
</div>


<label style="display: none" id="labelCPF">CPF:</label>
<input type="text" id = "cpf" placeholder="CPF" style="display: none">

<label style="display: none" id="labelCNPJ">CNPJ:</label>
<input type="text" id = "cnpj" placeholder="CNPJ" style="display: none">
```

Quanto a mascara da uma olhada nesse cara aqui:
[Mascaras em Jquery](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)